# Slidebar value to filter Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm currently working on my first AngularJS project so I have no Angular experience at all. In my html, I show a slidebar with two handle. This way I can get a minimum and a maximum value. This happens here:

```
  <div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="width-min">Width</label>
    <input type="range" name="width-min" id="width-min" value="5" ng-value="5"  min="3" max="53.5" ng-model="minWidth">
    <label for="width-max">Width</label>
    <input type="range" name="width-max" id="widthe-max" value="35" ng-value ="53"  min="3" max="53.5" ng-model="maxWidth">
  </div>
```

I have a small set of data in my controller:

```
 $scope.products = [
{partNumber: "5400-003-412", specific:"V",width:5.5,MT:0.25,CT:0.33,L:18},
{partNumber: "5400-003-410", specific:"DC",width:5.5,MT:0.25,CT:0.33,L:11.5},
{partNumber: "5400-003-102s3", specific:"V",width:19.5,MT:0.38,CT:0.61,L:25.4}
];
```

As  you guys can see every product has a width. I only want the show those products with a width between the minimum and maximum value selected on the sliderbar. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular [`filters`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for that. A filter can be a `string`, `Object`, or `function()`

A solution is to include a filter while rendering the list.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="product in products | filter : filterByWidth"
    {{product.partNumber}} - {{product.width}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your controller, you can include a filter function (for this example it's `filterByWidth`).

```
$scope.filterByWidth = function(product, index, array) {
  if (product.width > $scope.minWidth &&
    product.width < $scope.maxWidth) {
    return true;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! This totally worked!  A bit strange I didn't came up with this myself. Simple solution actually, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
     <div ng-repeat="product in products">
       <div ng-if="product.width > minWidth && product.width < maxWidth ">  {{product.partNumber}}</div>
     </div>
```